# Can a process running in a linux container communicate with another process running on the host OS via IPC?

Tags: lxc, ipc

I have 2 processes A and B. Currently, both A and B are running on the same OS (RHEL6.2) and the processes can intercommunicate via TCP sockets.

My objective is to run process B in a Linux Container and still have it communicate (send/receive messages/signals) with process A on the host OS.

I've been unable to find a clear answer after a few days of searching the web. Can this be done or are containers completely isolated? If so, how can I achieve this? I'm very new to this concept.

Comment: What is the "container" technology you're talking about here? Docker or something else? If it is `docker` then the answer is currently no: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889187/is-it-possible-to-share-memory-between-docker-containers. If you can use shared memory (mmap) b/w the 2 containers I believe you can do this.

Comment: BTW, given that docker is making use of the Kernel's namespace facilities, and that IPC is one of these namespaces, I would assume that it's only a matter of time before you'll be able to do this. http://www.sebastien-han.fr/blog/2014/02/03/crash-course-next-generation-servers-with-containers/

Comment: Our servers in the field are running on RHEL6.2. Docker only supports 6.5 and up so i am not using docker. As a matter of fact I am yet to find out how to cleanly get lxc on any RHEL other than RHEL7, since lxc is included. But installing lxc is a less pressing issue if conceptually, i cant get my container process to talk to the host process. I believe the --net flag is more along the lines of what i want to achieve. both container and host sharing the same IPC namespace should allow for their processes to communicate. I'll investigate this. Thank you.